# Como unificar dois arquivos CSSs

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

Estou fazendo um projeto *Spring MVC 4.2*.

Nesse projeto tenho mais de um arquivo *CSS* e mais de um *JS*.

O que eu quero é transformar todos os arquivos *CSSs* em um único *ALL.css* e que este arquivo seja `minify`.

O que eu tenho funcionando é uma configuração que coloca os recursos em um diretório pre definido. A configuração é essa:

```
VersionResourceResolver versionResolver = new VersionResourceResolver()
                .addFixedVersionStrategy(version, "/**/*.js", "/**/*.css")
                .addContentVersionStrategy("/**");


        registry.addResourceHandler("/public-resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
               .setCachePeriod(1)
                    .resourceChain(true)
                    .addResolver(versionResolver)
                    .addTransformer(appCacheTransformer);
```

Com isso eu consigo acessar os arquivos na *view* assim:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<spring:url value="/resources/css/magnific-popup.css"/>">
```

O resultado no HTML é esse:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/MeuProjeto/public-resources/css/magnific-popup.css">
```

Tudo funciona.

Existe alguma forma de unificar os CSSs em um único arquivo all.css e chamar assim? O Spring é capaz de fazer isso?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<spring:url value="/resources/css/all.css"/>">
```

Eu achei alguns plugins que supostamente funcionariam para isso, achei o [wro4j](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/GettingStarted) que nem tem como começar a usar, ao adicionar a dependência no `pom.xml` ele não consegue ler o repositório.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Vou atualizando para incluir tentativas e dúvidas na pergunta, acho que vai ajudar os futuros leitores.

A primeira tentativa com o minify-maven-plugin.

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-minify</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                                <cssSourceDir>resources/css</cssSourceDir>
                                <cssSourceFiles>
                                    <cssSourceFile>Site.css</cssSourceFile>
                                    <cssSourceFile>style.css</cssSourceFile>
                                </cssSourceFiles>
                                <cssFinalFile>all.css</cssFinalFile>
                                <jsSourceDir>resources/js</jsSourceDir>
                                <jsSourceFiles>
                                    <jsSourceFile>index.js</jsSourceFile>
                                    <jsSourceFile>sendmail.js</jsSourceFile>
                                </jsSourceFiles>
                                <jsFinalFile>all.js</jsFinalFile>
                                <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>minify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Usei na view assim:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<spring:url value="/resources/css/all.css"/>">
```

Gerou a seguinte saída:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Isabele/resources/css/all.css">
```

Mas o arquivo **all.css** não está lá, dando 404.
A nível de teste eu não mudei os outros arquivos css da view, então os dois arquivo usados na configuração do plugin **Site.css** e **style.css** estão sendo usados exatamente como o **all.css** e os dois estão no local e respondendo.

Comment: Oi Ricardo, veja se o [minify-maven-plugin](https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md) resolve o seu problema. Usei para Javascript e CSS com sucesso.

Comment: Meu comentário foi sem pensar, eu não vi que a configuração era no `pom.xml`. Achei que seria em algum web.xml. Por isso falei da configuração java, até exclui o comentário. Obrigado

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, atualizei a pergunta com a tentativa do plugin, acho que entendi o que ele faz, na verdade é bem simples, só não entendi pq meu all.css não foi gerado. Você poderia da uma lida na atualização, por favor?

Comment: O arquivo `all.css` está no seu arquivo `war`? (Abra-o com uma ferramenta zip após rodar `mvn package`).

Comment: Agora que vi que o plugin também combina, vou deletar minha resposta, você adiciona a sua @Anthony

Comment: Deleta não. É boa a resposta!

Comment: Beleza então :)

Comment: Outra coisa, por que você está tentando minificar arquivos jsp? O minificador JavaScript só minifica arquivos JavaScript (geralmente com extensão .js).

Comment: Sei lá pq coloquei isso lá, corrigi aqui no teste e na pergunta.

Comment: @Douglas, deixa a reposta aí rapaz :).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, fiz um update project com o Marven, e até um export do projeto para gerar um `war`, não apareceu o `all.css` não, os outros arquivos estão lá. Estou achando que a configuração pode estar errada onde eu uso `<cssSourceDir>`. Os arquivos estão dentro de WebContent/resources/css

Comment: Ricardo, tente executar `mvn clean minify:minify` para forçar a execução do plugin. Depois procure pelo `all.css` na pasta `target` e nos subdiretórios também. Se o arquivo estiver lá, o plugin está funcionando e o problema pode ser ou que ele não está sendo executado no ciclo normal do maven (neste caso, tente adicionar uma tag `phase` como no [exemplo da documentação](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/usage.html)) ou pode ser que o arquivo não esteja sendo considerado na hora de empacotar o WAR, então teria que rever sua configuração deste plugin.

Comment: Além das dicas do utluiz, dê uma olhada no [demo](https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin/tree/master/demo), mesmo que você não declare um `cssFinalFile` era para ele gerar um `style.css` no diretório `css` dentro do seu WAR.

Answer (score 2):

Comentou do wro4j, deve ter tentado utilizar uma versão antiga, já removida do repositório.

Mas vai encontrar distribuições atualizadas aqui, escolha a qual te atender
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ro.isdc.wro4j

Existe também o repositório no [github](https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j) junto a [documentação](https://wro4j.readthedocs.org/en/stable/), porém é necessário criar um xml com nome de `wro.xml` e configurar o `web.xml`

> Mas a vantagem é de além de minificar, é possivel o realizar merge (unificar) que procura.

*Outras opções*

- https://jawr.java.net/
- https://github.com/mwanji/humpty
- https://github.com/JonathanWalsh/Granule

Comment: No inicio da documentação do wro4j ele ensina a configurar no web.xml, você saberia converter isso para configuração java?

Comment: Não sei, mas imagino se não é possivel implementar esse filtro em uma classe, problema é saber se ela ficaria visível para o wro4j. É triste, bibliotecas sem convenção sobre configuração.